# Delete old items Chrome Web Store

Tags: chrome-web-store

Does anybody know how I can delete "old" items in my Chrome Web Store account? I don't see a delete/remove button?

[image]

I am not really sure what to make of that. But I only need one version of the extension to be public at any time.

I guess I don't understand how to publish something without clicking "Add new item"...how can I publish a new version of "Suman Generator" without adding a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Until Now, You can't delete extension from that list. But You can overwrite the extension with other extension you want.
Example :
From : Suman Generator
To : Facebla bla bla

If You want to publish New Version of your extension, edit and upload in extension you already publish...

[image: Upload Button]

Don't Forget to change the version in manifest.json before uploading